# Regex to check the string from end of the string

Tags: regex, pentaho-data-integration

I need to select the substring of a text from an given keyword. For example

```
Str= 'book, painting'
```

I need to get output like ', painting'

So i gave regular expression like (•*)(\, •*) and collect group2 as an output.

But if the input is

```
Str= 'book, painting, instrument'
```

I am getting ', instrument' as an output but i should get ', painting, instrument'.

Comment: I am doing this in Replace in string step in pentaho data integration

Comment: This is an sample string and my code has name in this format so i need to get all the secondary names which will be after the first comma.. So there may be many names after primary name so i am not sure how many I can expect after first comma

Comment: Have you tried this? `(•*?)(\, •*)`

Answer (score 1):

To specify that the regex should start matching at the start of your text, use "^". Similarly, "$" can be used to match the end of your text, grabbing until the end of the string.

Your first reference should explicitly exclude commas, to ensure it only grabs the first column.

```
 ^([^,]*)(\, •*)$
```